# zf2 bjyauthorize not load login role

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2

I've installed bjyauthorize, I set provider from database, for role, rule, etc, everything loaded fine except that even if I'm logged in, bjyauthorize return only bjyauthorize-identity when I call `$serviceManager->get('BjyAuthorize\Service\Authorize')->getIdentity();`

I must mention if I call zf2 identity service user data get loaded.

please tell me what piece of code to write here to help you help me get an answer.

```
<?php

return array(
    'bjyauthorize' => array(
        // default role for unauthenticated users
        'default_role' => 'guest',
        // default role for authenticated users (if using the
        // 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\AuthenticationIdentityProvider' identity provider)
        'authenticated_role' => 'user',
        // identity provider service name
        'identity_provider' => 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\AuthenticationIdentityProvider',
        // Role providers to be used to load all available roles into Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl
        // Keys are the provider service names, values are the options to be passed to the provider
        'role_providers' => array(
            'Users\Authorize\Provider\Role\ObjectRepositoryProvider' => [
                    'object_manager' => 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default',
                    'role_entity_class' => 'Users\Entity\Role',
            ]
        ),
        // Resource providers to be used to load all available resources into Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl
        // Keys are the provider service names, values are the options to be passed to the provider
        'resource_providers' => array(
            'Users\Authorize\Provider\Resource\ObjectRepositoryProvider' => [
                'object_manager' => 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default',
                'resource_entity_class' => 'Users\Entity\Resource',
            ],
        ),
        // Rule providers to be used to load all available rules into Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl
        // Keys are the provider service names, values are the options to be passed to the provider
        'rule_providers' => array(
            'Users\Authorize\Provider\Rule\ObjectRepositoryProvider' => array(
                'object_manager' => 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default',
                'rule_entity_class' => 'Users\Entity\Rule',
            ),
        ),
        // Guard listeners to be attached to the application event manager
        'guards' => array(),
        // strategy service name for the strategy listener to be used when permission-related errors are detected
        'unauthorized_strategy' => 'Users\View\RedirectionStrategy',
        // Template name for the unauthorized strategy
        'template' => 'error/403',
        // cache options have to be compatible with Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory
        'cache_options' => array(
            'adapter' => array(
                'name' => 'memory',
            ),
            'plugins' => array(
                'serializer',
            )
        ),
        // Key used by the cache for caching the acl
        'cache_key' => 'bjyauthorize_acl'
    ),
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I asked for wrong service :

```
$authorize_ = $serviceManager->get('BjyAuthorize\Service\Authorize');
```

The good one was :

```
$authorize = $serviceManager->get('BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ProviderInterface');
```

second one is ok for request logged in user roles